# Floating controls in dynamic width container in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, floating

I am new to XAML and is trying to at runtime add a dynamic number of buttons to a container which scales with the current window width and height.
The buttons should be centered and placed beside each other and if there are not enough space on one line, the button which is too wide is moved above the other buttons and so on, resulting in a "floating" behavior as known from HTML.

If there are enough buttons to scale the containers height larger than the window it should be possible to scroll in the container, this part i dont think is a problem but the "float" behavior i cannot figure out how to do.
I have tried with the available panels but none seem to suit this purpose and i am thinking about creating a custom control which positions child controls in the way i want, but there must be some way this can be achived using standard controls?

I am developing this in UWP as an universal app for both desktop and mobile.

Thanks for any input to my problem :)

Comment: Have you tried a Wrappanel?  This has the the "floating" or "wrap around" behavior that will bring the control that exceeds the size of the window down to the next available space to the bottom left.

Comment: In UWP the Wrappanel is replaced by VariableSizedWrapGrid with has the wrapping behavior i need, but it places controls in a grid layout and you need to specify rows and columns which i dont want. The controls should be positioned freely without any column definition.

Comment: [ItemsWrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid) doesn't require any such thing.

Comment: @ChrisW. from my testing ItemsWrapGrid still positions elements in grid meaning each element gets the same width available in each column. And i also cannot see that it supports centering elements per row?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you mention anywhere those specific requirements, must not have paid enough attention reading your post.

Comment: Are your buttons all in different widths? If they have the same width, a `GridView` may solve this problem, you don't need to specify rows and columns, and it supports centering elements per row.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT the buttons have different width depending on the text of the button, so i cannot use the layout of the grid controls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could achieve what you want with a combination of a [RelativePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel.aspx) and a couple of [VisualStates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.aspx) and visual state triggers such as [AdaptiveTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger.aspx) or some from the [WindowsStateTriggers](https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers) library. With these you could define different visual states, each representing a different layout of buttons and define triggers that apply these states based on some conditions (most likely based on the size of your container). There's a very good example of this approach described in [this blog post](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/04/building-adaptive-layout-in-windows-10-with-relativepanel-and-adaptivetrigger/).

Comment: I use visual states in other parts of the application, but i cannot see how i could apply them for this particular purpose? Each button needs to be positioned individually and should shift x and y position depending on the containers size and there by the size of the buttons on the left and right of each button. I think i need an example of the basic use of AdaptiveTriggers where dynamic controls are positioned depending on other controls and their parent container? :)

Comment: Please check my links to WindowsStateTriggers and to Laurent Bugnion's post about combining RelativePanel and visual states + triggers, and get back to questions after that! ;)

Comment: I _have_ reviewed the links you provided, even before you posted them since i have Googled for ages trying to find a solution. I have tested the RelativePanel but the Align properties is not versatile enough, you can position a control to the Right, Left, Top and Bottom of another control but i need to make each "row" of controls position fluidly and not snap to other controls. So perhaps it's me being new to XAML and UWP, but I simply cannot see how to achive this using standard controls :)